# Model Field Choice and Unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-models, choicefield

I'm creating a "Field.choice" in django that define the priority statuses available for items. When I try to display an item, I'm stuck with the constants (in CAP) when I'd like to display/ use the human-readable name.

For instance, an Item with  the priority (MAITRISE, u'Maitrisé') with be displayed as MAI (value of the constant MAITRISE) instead of 'Maitrisé'.

How do I change that? How can I choose which element of the tuplue (MAITRISE, u'Maitrisé') I want to use?

Here is my field choice (I add or change a priority status to an item)

```
priority = models.CharField(max_length = 50,choices=PRIORITY_CHOICE,default=PRIORITAIRE)

MAITRISE = 'MAI'
IMPORTANT = 'IMP'
PRIORITAIRE = 'PRIO'

PRIORITY_CHOICE = (
    (MAITRISE, u'Maitrisé'),
    (IMPORTANT, u'Important'),
    (PRIORITAIRE, u'Prioritaire'),
     )
```

The view

```
def display(request):

    priority_scale = MemoryItem.PRIORITY_CHOICE
    # Mixed list
    mem_list = list(MemoryItem.objects.all().order_by('?'))
    item = mem_list[0]

    return render(request, 'memory/display.html',{
        'item':item,
        'priority_scale':priority_scale,
        })
```

The template

```
<div class="row">

    <!-- x,y tuple is like MAITRISE, u"maitrisé" avec MAITRISE = MAI -->
    {% for x,y in priority_scale %}
        <!-- if the priority status of the item match the current loop in priority scale list => button should be red -->
        {% if y == item.priority  %}
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <a href=""><button class="btn btn-danger">{{y}}</button></a>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                 <a href=" {% url 'memory:change_priority' mem_id=item.id new_priority=x %}">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">{{y}}</button></a>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div><br>
```

Sure it's basic skills but the documentation is a bit short on this

Comment: `item.priority` will return `MAI` not `Maitrisé`. If you want to get the value `Maitrisé`, you should call [`item.get_priority_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fields that have `choices`, calling `instance.fieldname` returns the actual value of the field. If you rather want the verbose value of the field from the choices tuple, you need to call [`instance.get_FOO_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display). For your case, it'd be `item.get_priority_display()`. But remember you cannot call functions like that in Django templates. So calling `item.get_priority_display` will get you the display value.